# SSH into macOS with android(Termux)

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ssh

I installed ubuntu into my android phone using termux, and tried to ssh into my macbook using

```
ssh username@ip_address
```

However, I get a connection timeout error every time.

I'm missing something here. I understand that we need a public key(is it related to the ip address?) and a private key to set up connection, but i couldn't find where this information is. Also, it would help if you could differentiate the ubuntu I have installed in my mobile with the runs which runs on pcs.

Comment: Have you installed or enabled an ssh server on your Macbook?

Comment: How are the two devices networked, and what IP address are you using (public or private)? You do not need a public & private key; that's something you can set up (& it's a good idea to), but not there by default. One thing, though: do you have a good (secure) password set on the Mac? If not, there's a significant chance you'll be hacked over ssh -- it's under constant attack by bots on the Internet.

Comment: So what I understand is that sshing allows me to access my files and run them from a remote device(right?). Im using wifi and no local connections. What do I explicitly need to set up for it to work? Ive generated keys on Mac and linux on android.